# Is this right for a factory method producing singletons?

Tags: c#, singleton, maui, factory-pattern

I've got this bit of code for a factory method to produce singletons. I have a small MAUI app and want to have persistent global data.

```
public static class FactoryService
{
    private static BudgetViewModel budgetViewModelInstance;
    private static AccountsViewModel accountsViewModelInstance;
    private static PayeesViewModel payeesViewModelInstance;

    public static BaseViewModel BuildViewModel(Type type)
    {
        if(type == typeof(BudgetViewModel))
        {
            budgetViewModelInstance ??= new BudgetViewModel();
            return budgetViewModelInstance;
        }
        else if(type == typeof(AccountsViewModel))
        {
            accountsViewModelInstance ??= new AccountsViewModel();
            return accountsViewModelInstance;
        }
        else if(type == typeof(PayeesViewModel))
        {
            payeesViewModelInstance ??= new PayeesViewModel();
            return payeesViewModelInstance;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Can't build View Model. Invalid View Model: {type}");
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I want a view model reference, I have to cast the type I want before calling BuildViewModel:

```
BudgetViewModel budgetViewModel = (BudgetViewModel)FactoryService.BuildViewModel(typeof(BudgetViewModel));
```

Is this.... right? Is there a better way to accomplish this? I can't use static classes for the view models because they have to inherit from ObservableObject. (from the Community MVVM Toolkit)

Comment: One thing to consider with Singletons is to ensure their creation is thread safe. [Jon Skeet - Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton)

Comment: Is there a special reason why you not want to use the DI container from Maui which can solve that

Comment: @SirRufo I am wiring in async/await/Task.Run and I had to abandon the DI container from Maui in order to facilitate this.

Comment: I guess you are doing something basically wrong. ViewModels belong to the UI context and therefore to the UI thread context. There must not be such wiring and constructing inside a different thread context. Maybe you want to do it because of a time consuming constructor of the VMs - as I said you do something wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use generics. Something like this:

```
public static class FactoryService
{
    private static BudgetViewModel budgetViewModelInstance;
    private static AccountsViewModel accountsViewModelInstance;
    private static PayeesViewModel payeesViewModelInstance;
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public static T BuildViewModel<T>() where T : BaseViewModel, new()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(BudgetViewModel))
        {
            if (budgetViewModelInstance == null)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (budgetViewModelInstance == null)
                    {
                        budgetViewModelInstance = new();
                    }
                }
            }

            return budgetViewModelInstance as T;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(AccountsViewModel))
        {
            if (accountsViewModelInstance == null)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (accountsViewModelInstance == null)
                    {
                        accountsViewModelInstance = new();
                    }
                }
            }

            return accountsViewModelInstance as T;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(PayeesViewModel))
        {
            if (payeesViewModelInstance == null)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (payeesViewModelInstance == null)
                    {
                        payeesViewModelInstance = new();
                    }
                }
            }

            return payeesViewModelInstance as T;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Can't build View Model. Invalid View Model: {typeof(T)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke like this:
`var viewModel = FactoryService.BuildViewModel<BudgetViewModel>();`

Comment: Well a Dictionary and use of Activator would reduce a lot of code and make it DRY

Comment: @SirRufo I'd usually opt to use  Lazy<T> for singletons. Lots of different ways to implement.

Comment: There are lots of ways but only a few are clean and dry

Comment: @SirRufo this code is not violating DRY principles. Sure, a dictionary would make it less lines of code - but the original post was not using a dictionary. `Activator` would arguably be less performant than `new()` because `Activator` is using reflection to create the instance.